# Undefined variable error when calling a function from another snippet

Tags: php, scope

The following PHP page

```
<?php
$a = "World";

function say() {
    echo $a;
}
?>

Hello, <?php say(); ?>
```

fails with:

```
Undefined variable: a in test.php on line 5
```

Could someone explain me why, and what is the best way to fix this?

Comment: It's covered in the "[Variable Scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)" section of the PHP manual.

Comment: really? can't find that in there

Comment: It's at the very top of the page... the text under the first code box explains function scope, the second code box displays code equivalent to yours, the text under it explains why it doesn't work and how to fix it, the first Example box contains the fixed code, equivalent to code given in zan's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to define variable as global inside the function

```
<?php
 $a = "World";

function say() {
global $a;
echo $a;
}
 say(); 
?>
```