# PHP variables in scraper function

Tags: php, web-scraping, scraperwiki

I'm using ScraperWiki to build a simple screen scraper getting links from an online store. The store has multiple pages, so I want to get all the links from the first page, find the "next" button in the pager, go to that url, find all the links from there, go to next page, and so on and so forth.

Here's where I'm at. The ScraperWiki uses Simple HTML DOM and CSS selectors:

```
<?php 
require 'scraperwiki/simple_html_dom.php';  

function nextPage(){
    $next = $html->find("li.pager-next a"); 
    $nextUrl = 'http://www.domain.com';
    $nextUrl .= $next->href . "\n"; 
    getLinks($nextUrl);
} 

function getLinks($url){    // gets links from product list page   

    $html_content = scraperwiki::scrape($url);
    $html = str_get_html($html_content);

    $x = 0;

    foreach ($html->find("div.views-row a.imagecache-product_list") as $el) { 
        $url = $el->href . "\n";  
        $allLinks[$x] = 'http://www.domain.com';
        $allLinks[$x] .= $url;
        $x++;
    }

    nextPage();
}

getLinks("http://www.domain.com/foo/bar");


print_r($allLinks);

?>
```

The `getLinks()` function works fine when NOT in a function, but I'm getting "undeclared variable" errors when I put them in a function. My question is:

In PHP can I declare empty variables/arrays to use throughout the script, like in Javascript? I've read a few answers here on Stack which seems to imply that there is no need to declare, which seems odd.

Comment: Variable scope still exists. Either use parameters, or invite "`global`" variables into each function.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Undefined variable error when calling a function from another snippet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14301958/undefined-variable-error-when-calling-a-function-from-another-snippet)

Comment: @mario Cheers for that, couldn't find a good reference. Here the issue is that before the function is called the variables don't have value, so I can't declare them. What's the best way to pass them through in the example above?

Answer (score 1):

If you had shown the whole error it would probably be something like

> Undefined variable: $getLinks

Probably because what you meant was this:
     `getLinks($nextUrl);`

Not this: 
    `$getLinks($nextUrl);`

It works fine outside of the `nextPage` function because you are calling it correctly there.

Comment: Nope, I'm getting: `PHP Notice: Undefined variable: allLinks in /home/scriptrunner/script.php on line 33` when I try to `print_r($allLinks);` at the end of the script.

Comment: That means $allLinks is undefined. Define it as an empty array. If that `for` loop never runs, then $allLinks never gets defined.

Comment: use `$allLinks = array();` just after your include and I think you'll be set. Your scraper isn't returning anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
class ScraperWiki{
    public $variable;
    protected $variable;
    private $variable;

    // here you have the option of choosing how your functions and variables are treated...


     private function getLinks(){...}



     public function someOtherFunction(){
          $this->getLinks(); //will call the function in this Class
     }
}
```

Plus you have a syntax Error  $getLinks($nextUrl); should be getLinks($nextUrl)

Comment: He's building it procedurally, he had no intention of turning it into a class.

Comment: building a class is not always best practice. If you don't need the features of OOP, then you're adding overhead for no reason.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution myself with a bit of help from other answers - had to declare $allLinks at the start of the script, outside of any functions. In Javascript that would be enough to make it global, but in PHP it looks like you have to also declare it as global INSIDE functions, like this:

```
$allLinks = array();

function foo(){
    global $allLinks
    ...//stuff
}
```

This finally got my code working.